# Posts are not saved through the checkbox

Tags: php

I have tried in many ways to fix it but without success.
I'm trying to sort categories through the checkbox but it does not work. The post is made public during editing but the checkbox is not active and after the post update is checkbox removes the id and the post loses from the category.

```
<form name="addpost" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="form-group m-b-20">

<label for="exampleInputEmail1">Category</label>
<br>
<?php

$ret=mysqli_query($con,"select id,CategoryName from  tblcategory where Is_Active=1");
while($result=mysqli_fetch_array($ret))
{ 

?>
<input type="checkbox" name="category" id="category" value="<?php echo htmlentities($result['id']);?>"><?php echo htmlentities($result['CategoryName']);?><br>

<?php } ?>
<button type="submit" name="update" class="waves-effect waves-light pull-right butoni">Update </button>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Your category input has the same id="category" in the while loop this is wrong and will give you no options to use it later, you need to give it an id="category<?php echo $result['id'];?>"  for example - like this it will differ and appear in a different location... I also recommend using this method for the name - if you are planning on submitting the post you can't submit multiple $_POST['category'] it won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="category" id="category" value="<?php echo htmlentities($result['id']);?>"><?php echo htmlentities($result['CategoryName']);?><br>
```

is placed in a loop... so there are more than one of these yes?!
We can't use the same id, and name for multiple inputs of a form or in html ...  instead :

```
<input type="checkbox" name="category[]" id="category<?php echo $result['id'];?>" value="<?php echo htmlentities($result['id']);?>"><?php echo htmlentities($result['CategoryName']);?><br>
```

this will make things appear in one after the other...

if you want the box to be checked add an if in the loop

```
if($result['something'] should be checked){ ?>
  <input type="checkbox" name="category[]" id="category<?php echo $result['id'];?>" value="<?php echo htmlentities($result['id']);?> checked "><?php echo htmlentities($result['CategoryName']);?><br><?php
} else {
   <input type="checkbox" name="category[]" id="category<?php echo $result['id'];?>" value="<?php echo htmlentities($result['id']);?>"><?php echo htmlentities($result['CategoryName']);?><br><?php
}
```

just fix the:

```
if($result['something'] should be checked){rest of the code}
```

to be correct according the when checkbox should be checked and when not.

For checkbox to be checked we add a checked in the input line.

Comment: Thanks dear, I tested it but it does not work either, during the update or after the publication of a news item through the checkbox.
Checkbox does not check the box

Comment: @root I have added in my answer how to set the checkbox checked if ...

Comment: If you are talking about something that happens after the page loads, it's impossible in php without a reload to change data.

Comment: Thanks so much dear! How can I reload the code you gave me? This can be done through ajax?

Comment: If we know which ones should be checked on the page load before the form we are home free.... with just PHP as I showed in my example. How do we know if input should be checked or not? is it in the db response?

Comment: No checked is not in db is id "category" as a name that sets the value so I want through the checkbox to set the value for category and save as selected. From your code the categories get the correct value but do not save it as checked.
https://ibb.co/sbM6R2f

Comment: I will try to be a little clearer : How do you know/decide whether the input line should be checked or not? by what data? some id numbers ? what is the rule here?

Comment: Dear to be and I clearer, checked or not I put it for test I thought it would work. I removed it.